# How to make a class object iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following point class:

```
import math

class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

   # def __iter__(self):
 #       return iter(int(self.x))
 #       return iter(int(self.y))
        return self

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)


    def distance(self, self2):
         return math.sqrt((self2.x - self.x) ** 2 + (self2.y - self.y) ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

I want to make 'points' iterable so that the following is possible:

```
point = Point(2, 3)
x, y = point
print(x)
    2
print(y)
    3
```

If you see my commented code, that is what I attempted but it says TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Point'. Any ideas on how to correctly do this?

Comment: @YiFei No, that isn't an iterator.

Comment: All of the below answers are correct. Is there a specific one which has the most advantages

Comment: @user10200421 That's why I wrote explanations for how the different ways all work, instead of just giving you code. Generally, after you understand them all, it's obvious which one is simplest for a given case. I think in this case, the generator is the simplest, which is why I put it first (and presumably why Sunitha and Ajax gave the same thing, without explanation, as the whole answer), but you should try to understand all of them before deciding.

Comment: As a side note: Do you want your `Point` objects to be mutable? Because, if not, this might be a great job for [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). (In fact, it's the example in the `namedtuple` docs.) That way, you get iteration for free, and indexing (I think it makes sense for, e.g., `pt[1]` to be the `y` value), and `__init__` (actually `__new__`, but don't worry about that), and `__repr__`, comparison operators, errors that prevent you from accidentally mutating a `Point`, and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: I want to be able to mutate the points using multiple mathematical operations later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.x
    yield self.y
```

---

To make something iterable, you need your `__iter__` method to return an iterator.

You can't just `return self`, unless `self` is already an iterator (which means it has a `__next__` method). But you don't want `points` to be an iterator, you want it to be iterable over and over.

You can't `return iter(int(self.x))` then `return iter(int(self.y))`, for two reasons. First, after you `return`, your function is done; any code that happens after that never gets run. Second, you can't call `iter` on an `int`. (Also, there's no reason to call `int` on an `int`.)

---

You could fix that last set of problems by creating an iterable out of each `int`, like a single-element list, iterating that iterable, and then delegating to it with `yield from` instead of `return`. Using `yield` or `yield from` in a function makes it a generator function, and the generators created by generated functions are iterators:

```
yield from iter([self.x])
yield from iter([self.y])
```

… but this is kind of silly. Once we know we want a generator, we can just `yield` the values we want to be iterated. Hence the code at the top.

---

Alternatively, you could explicitly create a single-element iterables for both elements and chain them together and return that:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return itertools.chain(iter([self.x]), iter([self.y]))
```

But that's also silly. Chaining two iterators over single-element lists is the same as just iterating a two-element list:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter([self.x, self.y])
```

---

Finally, rather than relying on a generator, list iterator, `chain`, or other iterator type that comes with Python, you can always write one explicitly:

```
class PointIterator:
    def __init__(self, point):
        self.values = [point.x, point.y]
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.values.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class Point:
    # ... other code
    def __iter__(self):
        return PointIterator(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `yield`:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def __iter__(self):
    yield self.x
    yield self.y

a, b = Point(4, 5)
print([a, b])
```

Output:

```
[4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a special `__iter__(self)` method, which should return an *iterator*. Add something like

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter([self.x, self.y])
```

Comment: When I try this I get TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'

Answer (score 1):

Your `__iter__` method should yield x and y values

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield self.x
    yield self.y
```

With this, you get the following output

```
>>> point = Point(2, 3)
>>> x, y = point
>>> print (x)
2
>>> print (y)
3
>>>
```